how to make """if __name__ != "__main__":""" work as """if __name__ == "__main__":"""
Greetings to all python coders.
Considering an old script which is designed for running directly. It looks like:
print("hello world")
print("hello world")
print("hello world")

Now we want to make it part of a package to import.
Then you must insert this code and makes many indentation blocks
if __name__ == "__main__":
[indentations]print("hello world")
[indentations]print("hello world")
[indentations]print("hello world")

It prevent unwanted execution of codes below after you import your file.
But this needs many indentation blocks (manually added or by IDEs) in your code and it also makes the diff command show useless differences. So now let's consider a minimal modification to the code. Maybe just put a single line like
if __name__ != "__main__": return
print("hello world")
print("hello world")
print("hello world")

So this will be a single new line and I expect it can do the same thing as __name__=="__main__". Thus, it will be a minimal modification.
I haven't found good explanations about this topic online and maybe you can share some ideas. return may not be a suitable one here but could there be a better approach?

To be honest, I don't really understand what your purpose is. In fact, if you still have doubts about what the if __name__ == "__main__": statement does, I encourage you to read this wonderful answer. However, I guess you might be interested in using pass as an empty statement. More on it here.

Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve.

@TheP if …: pass literally won’t do anything, you may as well omit it for the same result.

Just get yourself a decent IDE or editor that has a hotkey for increasing the indentation of a block of code so that you can move it into the if block. Or even better, an IDE that can turn a block of code into a new function so that you can have a proper main() function

@deceze I know, but as I don't really understand what the OP wants, I prefer to provide alternatives ¯_(ツ)_/¯

thank for the comments. I just updated the code. Homer512 mentioned an IDE and it will make it work for sure. But I am asking is it possible to add a single line without putting extra indentation blocks to the code and it works exactly like "if name == "main". Is it possible?

I see what you mean after the edits. I think that, if a file is intended to run a lot of code, it should not be eligible as a module to import, unless strictly necessary. What I mean is that, if your file contains a lot of code, it could be maybe considered a script instead of a module, and thus run separately. However, if you need it to be a module anyway, you will need to apply the if __name__ == "__main__" condition and indent all the code inside it.

it doesn't have to be many indentations: select all your code and hit tab just once and voilà

@folengateis I guess what the OP means is that the code can already have many indentations due to nested conditions, loops, etc., and that this would be adding an extra one for all lines, making overall code indentation even bigger.

the reference solved my problem! so the answer is "NO".
